# Qt How to copy 2. and 3. index of char array to quint16?

Tags: qt, casting, type-conversion

I am trying to take 2. and 3. index content values from a char[3] array. How can I take these two bytes to copy, equaling to quint16 variable.

Comment: little endian or big endian?

Comment: @ratchetfreak little endian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, for example:

```
char foo[3] = { 0x99, 0xEF, 0xBE };

quint16 bar = (quint8)(foo[1]) + (((qint8)(foo[2]))<<8);

qDebug() << hex << bar;
```

Output:

```
beef
```